# Is it possible to login via link into customer community directly

Tags: community, customer-community, login

I am working on some notifications module, where customer will receive an email with a link. Now the ask is if user can login into community by clicking the link only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not look like possible unless you implement your own login functionality.

Because to create these types of link either you need username, password (Which I don't think its possible in your case).

Or you need to generate some type of token (Which will expire some time).

So this does not look like achievable solution.

You can try one thing. Create a public page: Then a URL. In the url pass the URL of public site and a custom token in paramter. Store the token in system as well.  Now when user access the page then using the username and token validate the user and show him the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user can login clicking on the link.

If user wants to create cases then credentials are required.

Refer [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

> Even without communities licenses, external users have some access to your communities. Purchase Community Cloud licenses to allow members to log in or give access to Salesforce objects based on your business needs.
>
> If you intend to use your community as a public knowledge base for unauthenticated (or guest) users, you can do so without purchasing communities licenses. For example, guest users can access publicly available community pages to read content, review knowledge articles, and perform tasks which do not require them to log in (such as creating cases).